Expo infinite app building on server reload
I am using expo 51.0.28 and am having a strange issue. When I run npm run start or npm expo everything is fine, I can use Expo Go and see my apps compile. The moment I stop the server (lets say I update my env file) and then run npm run start or npm expo again my apps on web, android, ios and when I use the Expo Go app on my iphone all say 'App downloading' (the initial compile screen) and nothing happens. It eventually will crash for a server timeout.
I have to close all VS code windows and when I reopen I can start again fine, its very annoying and hurting my workflow. Anybody run into this same issue?

This appears to be some sort of conflict with VS code and the expo build. By using an external terminal I was able to start/restart successfully.
